# SugarORM: Why is listAll method throwing NullPointerException?

Tags: java, android, orm, nullpointerexception

I have a `SugarRecord` object here:

```
public class Options extends SugarRecord<Options> {
    public boolean includeNumbers;
    public boolean includeLowercase;
    public boolean includeUppercase;
    public int charCount;
    public String includedChars;

    public Options () {}

    public static class Builder {
        //builder thingys here
    }
}
```

I will only save one `Options` object into the database. I created a method in a class called `Utility` to get this object:

```
public static Options getOptions () {
    List<Options> optionsList = Options.listAll (Options.class);
    if (optionsList.size () == 0) {
        //return the default if there isn't an entry.
        return new Options.Builder ().setCharCount (8)
                .setIncludedChars ("")
                .setIncludeLowercase (true)
                .setIncludeNumbers (true)
                .setIncludeUppercase (false).build ();
    } else {
        return optionsList.get (0);
    }
}
```

Now when I call the method in an activity to read the objects, a `NullPointerException` is thrown. Here is the call stack:

```
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: OPTIONS (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM OPTIONS
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1322)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1169)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1040)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1246)
            at com.orm.SugarRecord.find(SugarRecord.java:208)
            at com.orm.SugarRecord.listAll(SugarRecord.java:134)
            at com.passwordgen.util.Utility.getOptions(Utility.java:94)
            at com.passwordgen.OptionsActivity.onCreate(OptionsActivity.java:34)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:150)
            at
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1298)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I don't really understand why this happens, because I saved some other stuff using SugarORM, and they are all fine. Please tell me how I can fix this problem.

My guess is that my sugar record contains some stuff that cannot be put into a table, maybe boolean? But that should be fine, I am pretty sure SQL databases can store booleans.

Comment: post your database class

Comment: I am using SugarORM which doesn't require a data base class. For how sugar orm works, check it on github @IntelliJAmiya

Comment: Okay okay .I never knew that .Have a look here `no such table: OPTIONS`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I guess that is a bug with Sugar ORM